# Add a picture in the HTML canvas (jsketcher2D) and keep it on the back

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to develop a JavaScript application for modulating house plans with [jsketcher](https://github.com/xibyte/jsketcher). You can view project [here](https://github.com/damithnh/sketcherDev). For modulating plans, I need to load the plan on the canvas, then try to modulate with the tools present in the [jsketcher2D](http://web-cad.org/sketcher.html#__sample2D__). I've manged to load the plan but couldn't find a way to keep it below the other elements of the canvas. I need the elements which are drawn with jsketcher2D to be on top of the plan image. Could you please help me with this?
Thank you very much

modifications made to static/sketcher.bundle.js

Line 49532

```
function addPlan(){

  let canvas = document.getElementById('viewer');
  let plan = canvas.getContext("2d")
  let base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'img/back.png';
  plan.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
  }
```

Line 47461

```
addPlan();
```

Comment: A canvas is just a mass of the pixels, it doesn't contain any "elements". Create another canvas for the image, and show it under the actual canvas you use to draw "elements".

Comment: I need the zoom in out and pan functions to work on the plan image same as with elements

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, it's relatively easy to pan and zoom multiple canvases simultaneously.

Comment: Really, could you please tell me how to do it? Or point me in the right direction? Thank you very much. Been stuck at this for days now :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to show more code. The most likely reason this is happening is you have your addPlan() function running after you draw on the canvas. The first things drawn will be on the back of the canvas and the last things drawn will be above.

```
    addPlan(); // Background
    canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50); // will be on top of image
```

Comment: I've tried to change the place of `addPlan()` but couldn't figure out where. sketcher.bundle.js has 45k+ lines :-|

Comment: Use Ctrl-Find to find code inside your script. It has helped me a lot.